# Boolean evaluation of page item is incorrect

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, boolean-logic

I have a report in an APEX page and it has multiple columns with results (rows count) that go from anywhere between 10,000 and 1,000,000 (1M) records.

There is a conditional where clause that I have, and it uses a page item's value in order to determine or restrict the results that are shown... it looks something like this:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
AND (:P2_STARTDATE IS NULL OR TO_DATE(:P2_STARTDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') < creation_date)
```

I believe that at anytime I do enter a value for the `P2_STARTDATE` page item then the comparison takes place, but when I do not enter any value for the page item then it is supposed to be `NULL` and boolean operation should just return TRUE for the `P2_STARTDATE IS NULL` evaluation...

The query makes the execution time take as much as 45+ seconds when searching in 0.5M rows, which is not acceptable. I wrote the following change to test my theory:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM ...
WHERE deleted_flag = 'N'
AND (:P2_STARTDATE IS NULL) -- comment the rest of the evaluation....
```

It evaluates immediately to NULL and returns the same resultset 0.5M+ in about 1 second... now, if I do set a value then the resultset is empty, obviously.

So the question is, how can I make Oracle APEX evaluate quickly to TRUE that expression? Thanks for any tips, workarounds, or solutions that you may offer.

Comment: Have you checked the session state info to make sure P2_STARTDATE really is NULL? How about the debug log? Have you tried running the same query from sqlplus to see if it also takes a long time?

Comment: Hey @eaolson, when checking the session for the value of P2_STARTDATE it is just empty, and its status is either _Updated_ or _Reset to Null_...

Comment: Just a hunch: Have you set up the report with `Enable Partial Page Refresh` = `Yes`? If so, have you included P2_STARTDATE in the `Page Items to Submit`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it is safe to assume that the SQL engine is using short-circuit evaluation on your OR.

Try this:

```
AND (:P2_STARTDATE IS NULL 
     OR 
      (:P2_STARTDATE IS NOT NULL 
       AND TO_DATE(:P2_STARTDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') < creation_date)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe the second part of your query is sargeable - it cannot use an index.  Plus your example has nothing to do with searching for the actual result set.

One way is to convert (OUTSIDE of this query) the bound variable to the correct datatype, so that the query becomes able to use the index on creation_date (there is an index on creation_date, right?)

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
AND :P2_STARTDATE IS NULL OR creation_date > :newdatevariable;
```

In any event get the function to_date out of there and pass in a constant.

Comment: Jim, my question does not necessarily have to do with how sargeable or useful an index is, but rather with the proper/unproper evaluation of the WHERE clause and the values that the page item is being checked against. And yes, there is an index on creation_date field... :)

Comment: The problem I am having is that the engine seems to be evaluating the creation_date field against the page item's value, even though this is NULL and should've just returned TRUE when evaluated against being NULL or not.